# ASP.net repeater, scroll 3 at a time

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a list of data that I need to display in a web page 3 at a time

The first needs to be displayed in a div called "left" , the second in a div called "centre" and the third in a div called "right".

And I need to be able to scroll through the data with a pager. And so the next 3 results will be displayed in a similar way, and so on till the end of the data set

Obviously the alternating templates in the repeater are not suitable for this.

Is there a smarter way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you wish to load the data from database when the scroll event occurs or do you load the data when the page loads for the first time and then only show the data when scrolling occurs?

Comment: I have all the data in memory in a collection. It usually contains about 20 items. And I need to display them 3 at a time

Comment: So at first 3 rows of your data gets rendered to the page. After each scroll you access the collection and renders the next 3 rows... Is this the case?

Comment: Well I havent implemented anything yet - just looking for suggestions. I was hoping to be able to bind the repeater's datasource to the collection and then specify something in the markup to render the different tags

Comment: Why don't you use a div with scrolling and the fill the div for the first time with the data from the collection?

Comment: it has to use pagination - that is in the UI design

Comment: Which event fires the paging for you, Mouse scroll or mouse click?

Comment: Here we are using a repeater and has provided pagination. But in this we are calling the database for each click and then showing the items corresponding to each page. Is your collection static. Isn't there any delete option in your recordset.

Comment: I think you are missing the point of the question - which is how to get the 3 records inside the appropriate div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a loop like this

for (int i = 3; i < enumerable.length + 3; i++)
{

```
  if (i % 3 == 0)
  { 
     // Put it in div 1
  {
  else if (i % 3 == 1)
  {
     // put it in div 2
  {
  else if (i % 3 == 2)
  {
     // put it in div 3
  {
```

}

The first time through, it will use div1, the second time div2, and the third time div3, and then the fourth time div1, and so on...